# Create floor heat map with DWG file for website

Tags: jquery, html, canvas, svg, autocad

I would like to create a floor map which show foot print of user or heat map based on user movement on floor. I'm not sure how to create this heat map by using .dwg file. I also need to show this live map on my website which give real time data on map and show where users are more (currently I have only .dwg file which is auto cad file where i have complete drawing of my floor plan).

I'm open to use any technology which supports on website and can be used with JavaScript, PHP etc. Is there any tool which can create a heat map for me and generate web based format to host that on my website?

Comment: So your problem is not creating the heatmap (if it is, check [this](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) but to actually get the base floor pan from a DWG file and into a canvas?

Comment: How are you planning to track the (X,Y) coordinates of people walking around the building? Cameras? Wearable tracking devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your problem's getting that DWG into a canvas, you can convert the DWG into an SVG first. Here is some [discussion on that](http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-2013-2014/How-to-convert-a-drawing-dwg-file-to-svg/td-p/3506036)

If what you want is to draw the heatmap in realtime, check [this](http://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/) instead

Comment: But how can i control the heatmap.js to not to draw on walls. I mean if i give x, y coordination it shows some time people out of floor... I'm new with this js is there any way to add or draw a boundary so it will not draw a value out of that.

Also want to know how to add map controls like zoom in zoom out on my floor map image???

Comment: I'm not sure what heatmap.js offers in the latest versions. One way of avoiding your problem would be to draw the non-walkable areas on the map right after you update the heatmap, effectively masking the heatmap. A better approach would be to look into heatmap.js, but last time I checked he was pretty much using gradients and circles, which are not very easy to make. Regarding zooming in and out, you might want to look at google maps like APIs, but you'll most likely have to redraw the whole heatmap everytime someone zooms.

Comment: Yes for map i need to redraw that each time. But do you know where i can see that working example with control my problem is canvas is not redrawing in proper way and its change the area often. I can see example with google map or some other map only but not with custom map. if you found anything here please share.

Once again thank you Miquel :)